# Insert from one form to two tables using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to insert a form to two MySQL Database using the PDO here is my code:
**pc_owner table:**
pcid
pcname,
pcphone

**pc_wo table:**
woid,
pcid,
probdesc

> ```
> <?php include('core/init.php'); ?>
>
> <?php
> //Create DB Object
> $db = new Database;
>
> //Run Query
> $db->query("INSERT INTO `pc_owner` (pcname, pcphone)
>                               VALUES (:pcname, :pcphone)
>           INSERT INTO `pc_wo` (probdesc)
>                               VALUES (:probdesc,lastInsertId())");
>
>
> //Bind Values pc_owner
> $db->bind(':probdesc', $_POST['probdesc']);
> $db->bind(':pcphone', $_POST['pcphone']);
> //bidn values to pc_wo table
> $db->bind(':probdesc', $_POST['probdesc']);
>
>
> //$db->bind(':pcphone', $_POST['probdesc']);
>
> if($db->execute()){
>   echo "Contact was added";
> } else {
>   echo "Could not add contact";
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

Database.php  class used

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array (
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION 
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO ($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }       // Catch any errors
        catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }


    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null ( $type )) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int ( $value ) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool ( $value ) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null ( $value ) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue ( $param, $value, $type );
    }


    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }


    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }


    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }


    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }


    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }


    public function beginTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }


    public function endTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }


    public function cancelTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }
}
```

How to use this class to insert to 2 tables

Comment: use `;` semi colons to separate the two insert statements, and use `prepare`

Comment: i tried that before submitting my question,

Comment: I just realized your whole attempt is wrong. give me a second.

Comment: You should be using [**transactions**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) for this

Comment: thank you David is there any way to provide an example